# How to pass the name of the item clicked on the on list item clicked through Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

How to pass the name of the item clicked on the on list item clicked through Intent? is this correct?

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, final int position, long id)
{ super.onListItemClick(l, view, positin, id);
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PowerpointActiv.class);
in.putExtra("string", String.valueof(position));
startActivity(in);
}
```

then in my PowerpointActiv

```
String nam = getIntent().getStringExtra("string");
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + nam;
```

i get error (java.runtimeExceptin: cannot instantiate activity ComponentInfo: Java.lang.nullpointerexception).. how to pass the String name of the item :( pls help :(

Comment: You must have a problem in your onCreate() on the `PowerpointActiv`. Also try to accept any of the answers on your other questions, or leave some feedback to the answers you get.

Comment: sorry still new here, and to android.. ill do that..
What kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name("string" in you'r case) must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.string".

this is from java doc:

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, String value) 
Added in API level 1
Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Parameters
name  The name of the extra data, with package prefix. 
value  The String data value. 

Returns
Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement
```

so change :

```
in.putExtra("string", String.valueof(position));
```

to:

```
in.putExtra("your.package.string", String.valueof(position));
```

and of curse:

```
String nam = getIntent().getStringExtra("string");
```

to:

```
String nam = getIntent().getStringExtra("your.package.string");
```

i dont know if thats your problem but it's a start

Comment: it worked! thanks i just had to transfer the line though to the onCreate().. now my new problem :( it reads a blank powerpoint :( if i place it in the res folder, it reads fine. but when i push the PPT to the sdcard through DDMS, it reads a blank powerpoint :(